# Dialog box from Service

Tags: android

I am running a service as soon as application starts. That service will keep checking SQLite for data. If it finds a certain data, a dialog box should pop up (user can be on any activity). Don't want to use notification. How do I pop up Dialog box from a service ?

Comment: Well, this is direct violation of guidelines! `Service` should never open dialogs directly. The only things `Service` can do is to show notification. It should never start activities or show dialogs.

Comment: Ok.... point noted. I will do the notification now.

Answer (score 0):

Short question is you cant. However, you can send an intent to your activity for it to be the one showing the dialog box, or you can start an activity that looks like a dialog.